# Remove update from Google Play Store (Developer Console)

Tags: android

Is there a way to remove an update from the Google Developer Console?
Players that already have downloaded that update can keep it, but for those who haven't, I don't want them to download it as well.

My current "solution" to this is to just push an old version of the app signed with a new version number to the Developer Console, but I guess there's a better way, which I haven't figured out yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Play Developer Console, select your application and select the "APK" menu option. This should display the current and previous versions of your APK. If you then click the "Switch to advanced mode" button, a "Move to Prod" button should appear next to previous APK versions. If able, these should allow you to move previous versions of your APK in production.

Comment: Uh, I didn't even see that button until now, thanks.
When I do this however, it tells me "Version 1 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 1 would receive version 2." If I then deactivate version 2, it says, that "It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 2 to version 1, which would occur when API levels in range 15+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and ..."